# SSL on CloudFront fails test

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, hsts

I'm hosting a static website on S3/Cloudfront. I have enabled SSL using an Amazon provided SSL certificate.

Unfortunately, the setup seems to be failing the [SSL tests](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=4xlabs.co).

Any idea what could cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should fail. The certificate AWS issued for you is valid for `*.4xlabs.co`. So `https://www.4xlabs.co/` or `https://subdomain.4xlabs.co/` will work, but `https://4xlabs.co/` will not.

Comment: Thanks, I incorrectly assumed that *.domain.com includes domain.com.

Comment: @chrisvdb it does not, but you can generate a cert that has domain.com as a Subject Alternative Name (SAN)